# MacBook Pro Retina and fonts rendering

Tags: macos, fonts, smoothing

I am using MPB retina. I have more than two years of a constant osx experience but what I can't stand is an OSX font rendering. That's simply uncomfortable for my eyes. Big amount of my work I do using external monitor (Nec 24') and fonts look even more blurry (terrible) on it.
Is there any official or unofficial way to change font rendering in OSX?
Any kind of custom kexts or patching would be appreciated. I can't find myself anything wrt this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lighter text rendering style by running

```
defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 1
```

and quitting and reopening applications to apply the changes.

[image]

Comment: You can achieve the same effect by simply unchecking checkbox in Prefs->General->'Use LCD font smoothing..'
That doesn't fix an issue with external monitor at all, making it look even worse.

Comment: `defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 1` doesn't disable LCD font smoothing, but it makes OS X use the light text rendering setting that was included in System Preferences in 10.5 and earlier. `defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 0` would disable LCD font smoothing, like the "Standard - Best for CRT" setting in 10.5 and earlier or unchecking "Use LCD font smoothing when available" in 10.6 and later.

Comment: Try values 0 through 4 (see comment above). Also, many people say that hi-res monitors are incorrectly detected unless connected via double-link DVI - the solution is forcing the monitor to run in RGB mode (not YCbCr as they would sometimes do if connected via mDP/Thunderbolt or HDMI)